# Написание слова "низкомотивированный"

Tags: орфография

Слитно или раздельно пишется слово "низкомотивированные"? Я считаю, что должно писаться раздельно, но в некоторых документах встречается слитное написание. Как правильно? Заранее благодарна.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, пожалуйста, отметьте его [как принятый](/help/accepted-answer) (галочка рядом с ответом).

Answer (score 1):

> НИЗКО… Первая составная часть сложных слов, соответствующая по
>   значению слову низкий (в 1, 2, 3 и 8 знач.), например: *низкобортный,
>   низкокалорийный, низкосортный, низколобый*. *(МАС)*

Таким образом, орфографически правильно написание *низкомотивированный* (ср. также *высокомотивированный*).